# Rails uninitialized constant error with boolean variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I hit this link:

```
link_to("Accept", invitation_sumbit_invitation_url(invitations), method: :put)
```

I get this error:

> uninitialized constant `InvitationsController`

The method in InvitationsController looks like this:

```
def sumbit_invitation
    @invi = @invitations.find(params[:id])
    @invi.update_attributes(accepted: true)
end
```

and routes is:

```
resources :invitations do
  put :sumbit_invitation
end
```

Comment: Does your InvitationsController start with `class InvitationsController < ApplicationController`? Is that file named `app/controller/invitations_controller.rb`? And can you please post the full error message including the file name and line number?

Comment: No, it starts with 'ControlPanel::InvitationsController < ControlPanel::ControlPanelController'. File naed is 'app/controllers/control_panel/invitations_controller.rb. Error message looks like this 
http://files.tinypic.pl/i/00797/pac6h950975b.png

Answer (score 0):

I propose you can follow the below steps to resolve your problem:

1/ run command `rake routes` to make sure your routes are correct?
In my opinion, it should be:

```
resources :invitations do
  member do
    put :sumbit_invitation
  end
end
```

2/ Make sure you URL is correct

`link_to("Accept", invitation_sumbit_invitation_url(invitations), method: :put)`

should be changed to

`link_to("Accept", invitations_sumbit_invitation_path(invitations), method: :put)`

Using `rake routes` to get correct path

4/ Make sure that your controller `InvitationsController` worked

P/S: It is better if you share your routes.rb file or logs `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

You controller is in the module `ControlPanel` and lives in the `control_panel` subfolder of your app's `controller's` folder, but your route doesn't have a corresponding `controll_panel` namespace defined.

Add a `controll_panel` namespace to your routes:

```
namespace :controll_panel do
  resources :invitations do
    put :sumbit_invitation
  end
end
```

This will make the `invitation_sumbit_invitation_url` invalid and you will have to change it to something like `admin_invitation_sumbit_invitation_url` or `invitation_sumbit_admin_invitation_url`. From the top of my head I am not sure how Rails handles the naming. Use `rake routes` in your console to get a list of all available route names in your app.

I this context I advise to read: [The Rails Guide: Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)